# Restricted movement of mouse cursor on the screen

Tags: raspbian, lxde, mouse

Is it possible to restrict mouse cursor movement?
For example, if I have a screen resolution 1024x768: I want move the mouse cursor only 0 up to 1000 in Y direction and 100 up to 600 in X direction.

Is it possible? How to do?

Comment: This sounds like a more general Linux question than a Raspberry Pi specific question. You might have more success on the Unix and Linux or Super User exchanges.